# How to add marker clusterer functionality in Android App?

Tags: android

i want to add markerclusterer functionality in my andriod app. i am using Google Maps Android API 2.In Api, i haven't see any description about that. Is there any alternate way to achieve that. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this google map extension

https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/